# Laravel Eloquent join throug pivot tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Unfortunately, I don't have that much experience with Eloquent yet. I try to create a query from three tables which have two pivot tables.

My tables:

[image]

My Models:

Player

```
class Player extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'players';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];
    public function layout(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Layout', 'layout_player', 'player_id', 'layout_id');
    }

    public function information(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Information', 'player_id');
    }
}
```

Layout

```
class Layout extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'layouts';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];
    public function player(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Player', 'layout_player', 'layout_id', 'player_id');
    }
    public function item(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item', 'item_layout', 'layout_id', 'item_id');
    }
}
```

Item

```
class Item extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'items';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];
    public function layout(){
        //return $this->hasOne(Layout::class);
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Layout', 'item_layout', 'item_id', 'layout_id');
    }
}
```

Starting from the player, I want to retrieve the current player, all layouts and the corresponding items. Unfortunately I can't do it.

I call up the player and layouts as follows:

```
Player::where('id',1)->with('layout')->get();
```

How do I additionally get all items in the query?

Comment: `Player::with('layout.item')->where('id',1)->get();` have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a relationship perfectly. Now from Player to layout you're getting it `with('layout')`. Try it.

```
$players = Player::with('layout.item')->where('id',1)->get();
```

It'll give you players along with layouts with items.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, I think you are almost there.

Add this to `Player` model too, like other methods you did.

```
public function contents(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Content');
}
```

To get all contents regarding a player write these in controller and pass it to view file.

```
$player = Player::findOrFail(1);
return view('path.to.file_name',compact('player'));
```

In view file

```
//get all contents of a player
@foreach($player->contents as $content)
    <p>{{ $content->text}}</p>
@endforeach

//get all layouts of a player
@foreach($player->layout as $layout)
    <p>{{ $layout->name}}</p>
@endforeach


//get all items of a player
@foreach($player->layout as $layout)
    <p>{{ $layout->name}}</p>
    @foreach($layout->item as $item)
        <p>{{ $item->name }}</p>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the quick answer. Unfortunately this does not solve my problem. 
I call the PlayerController via the api route and need all objects of the player in the form as return:

- player
- layout
- item

```
public function show($id)
{
    $player = Player::findOrFail($id);
    //$player = Player::where('id',$id)->with('layout')->get();
    return $player;
}
```

I get this response:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Testplayer","created_at":"2019-09-22 15:53:07","updated_at":"2019-09-22 15:53:07"}
```

But I need also the layouts and Items.

I hope you still understand my bad English.;)